# how do i move a picture forward in Adobe Premiere Pro

Tags: adobe-premiere

I have one picture that I want to use as the background picture of the other slide presentations. How do I change the stack of the pictures in Adobe Premiere Pro like I change layers in photoshop? Thank you.

Comment: i couldn't find answers to this question on google, or they were hard to understand, sorry...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept is the same in Premiere as in Photoshop, but the graphic manipulation is different because Photoshop has no concept of time (well, except for animated gifs, which are handled differently).

You'll need to use (at least) two lines of the timeline for video tracks.  By default, a new project has two video tracks and two audio tracks (probably; the default can be changed).

On the topmost video track, add the background image.  On the second-to-top video track, add the other content.  Video tracks are rendered from top to bottom, so whatever isn't "written" by the lower track is visible of the upper tracks.  In other words, the background image is rendered first, and then the display is overwritten by the second track.  That means the lower track needs to be masked or made partially transparent for the background to be visible.

By default, photos are given a default time length of 5.0 seconds.  You probably want to change that once you know how long the other tracks are.  So figure that out before guessing what the time length of the background is.  Then, using the pointer tool, grab the right end of the background image in the timeline and drag it to the required length.